# Blank screen while downloading images from Url and showing it in ListView android

Tags: android, json, image, android-alertdialog, progressdialog

I am getting a JSON response from a URL and convert it into a string. I get a URL for an image from the response. I want to download that image from the URL and show it into the ListView. But this takes a lot of time and a blank screen is shown until all the images are downloaded. The screen is shown for almost 40-50 seconds. Also the ListView is not very smooth. How can I prevent the blank screen from appearing?

Here is my code:-

```
String registerContet = "myUrl";

    String items;
    try
    {

        items = new FetchItems().execute(registerContet).get();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this).show(Home.this, "Fetching news items", "Please wait..");

        JSONArray jObject = new JSONArray(items);
        for (int i = 0; i < jObject.length(); i++)
        {
             JSONObject menuObject = jObject.getJSONObject(i);

             String title= menuObject.getString("Title");
             String description= menuObject.getString("BodyText");
             String thumbnail= menuObject.getString("ThumbnailPath");
             String newsUrl = menuObject.getString("Url");
             String body = menuObject.getString("Body");
             String newsBigImage = menuObject.getString("ImageBlobUrls");

                map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                map.put(SOURCETITLE, title);
                map.put(TITLE, description);
                map.put(THUMBNAILPATH, thumbnail);
                map.put(BODY, body);
                map.put(URL, newsUrl);
                map.put(IMAGEBLOBURLS,newsBImage);

                myNList.add(map);

    }
        itemsAdapter = new LazyAdapter(Home.this, myNList);
        if(pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing())
        {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        nList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

        nList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                    View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myDialog = new ProgressDialog(Home.this).show(Home.this, "Fetching news..", "Just a moment");


                HashMap<String, String> myMap = myNList.get(position);
                Intent nIntent = new Intent(Home.this,NDetails.class);
                newsIntent.putExtra("NItems", myMap);

                startActivity(nIntent);

            }
        });
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}









private class FetchItems extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ProgressDialog myDialog; 

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                HttpResponse response =null;
                String resultString = "";
                String myResponseBody = "" ;
                // Creating HTTP client
                        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        // Creating HTTP Post
                        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(params[0]);
                        try 
                        {
                            response = httpClient.execute(request);
                            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()== 200)
                            {
                                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                                if (entity != null)
                                {

                                    InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                                    myResponseBody = convertToString(inputStream);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                        }
                return myResponseBody;
            }





@Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                /*if(myDialog.isShowing())
                {
                    myDialog.dismiss();
                }*/
            }





            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
                /*myDialog = new ProgressDialog(Home.this);
                myDialog.setMessage("Loading");
                myDialog.show();*/
            }
```

Can anyone tell me how can I resolve this.
Thanks

Comment: You can use Universal Image Loader class for that and lazy loading too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Universal Image Loader`,  It caches your image and helps you in many ways.

Here are the features :

- Multithread image loading
- Possibility of wide tuning ImageLoader's
  configuration (thread executors, downloader, decoder, memory and disc
  cache, display image options, and others)
- Possibility of image
  caching in memory and/or on device's file system (or SD card)
- Possibility to "listen" loading process Possibility to customize
  every display image call with separated options

Here is the [link](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). you can read further and it is very easy to implement.

Comment: Can you tell me where and how can I use it in my code

Comment: Have you went through the link which i mentioned?

Comment: ya I have. It is a library. But  I am confused on how to use it

Comment: Download the jar file and add to your build path and rest of the thing is self explanatory.

Comment: You got it or need more help?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the separate child thread for loading image from server.
Best and efficient way to load image and save cache of image use universal Image Loader.

```
    load.displayImage(mimagebURL(), holder.image,option);
```

Using this library you dont need to create on thread for loading image.

Hope this will help you